# How to prevent backup messages to be printed

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren

In one of my servers, there are many databases which I take backup from the with Ola's script. Sometimes it happens that the backup job failed. But because many messages had been printed in job message I can not see the error message.
I have edited the script to prevent extra messages. But the built in messages that sql engine itself produces is not avoidable.

I mean these type of message:

```
Processed 504 pages for database 'ODS', file 'ODS' on file 1.
Processed 16 pages for database 'ODS', file 'ODS_Regualr_Data' on file 1.
Processed 16 pages for database 'ODS', file 'ODS_SALES_DATA' on file 1.
```

Is there any way to say not to print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFIK, there is no native solution to this but you could control that with following two options,

**Option 1:**

- Redirect the step output to a text file (dynamic), with the following you will get a file generated for every execution. You could also chose to append to single file but I wouldn't recommend that.

```
$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))\$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTDT))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTTM)).log
```

- Purge those files on a schedule basis.
- Exceptions would still report to job history.

  [image]

**Option 2:**

- Invoke backups using powershell command and redirect the output to `$null`.

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance . -Database Admin -Query 'EXEC Admin.dbo.DatabaseBackup @backupType=''LOG'' ' -QueryTimeout 65535 -Verbose" > $null
```

- *With this option both success and failre messages are discarded, probably.* Not recommended.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It has worked but with a little changes. When I copy the dynamic code it did not  work. Neither the messages had omitted nor the output had created. But when I gave the static path it works as expected.

Comment: np, did you check the output in default log location *where SQL Server Error Logs reside*? It is tested and works for me on 2019 version. You coud form your own format with all available tokens here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-ver15.

Answer (score -3):

You can use trace flag 3226, documented here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to avoid backup status messages being printed to the SQL Agent Job History, not the SQL Server error log.